# Clob functions doesn't work in Oracle 19.3.0.0

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle19c

I have been trying to use different functions on clob datatype in oracle 19.3.0.0 and none of them return values.

eg : -

```
dbms_lob.getlength(clob_data)
```

However any kind of functions on clob/blob datatype doesn't return values

`length(clob_data)`

These functions have been working fine previously in Oracle 12c. I recently upgraded to Oracle 19.3.0.0. Please educate me if there is any work around for this.

Comment: Can you provide a small, fully-reproducible test case that shows how CLOB functions don't work for you? For example, this simple code creates a table with a CLOB, populates it, and then calls a function on it that returns the correct length (4): `create table test1(a clob); insert into test1 values('asdf'); commit; select dbms_lob.getlength(a) length from test1;` Does that code work for you? If not, create something similar to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: "...recently upgraded..." - are you sure your data was migrated successfully?

Comment: @JonHeller. I executed the scenario that you sent and it seems to be working fine. 
But the issue is when i don't insert values to clob column shouldn't the get_length() function return 0 ? . Because it did earlier. it breaks my exiting code deployed on customer environment after the upgrade.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Yes, no issues with data.

Comment: I can overcome this problem by checking whether clob is null, but i would appreciate if someone can explain why. the get_length() doesn't return 0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to insert anything in clob column you should use empty_clob function

Test case

```
   SQL> create table test1 (id number,a clob);
    
    Table created.
    SQL> insert into test1 values (&id,&a);
    Enter value for id: 1
    Enter value for a: null
    
    1 row created.
    
    SQL> /
    Enter value for id: 2
    Enter value for a: empty_clob()
    
    1 row created.
    
    SQL> commit;
    
    Commit complete.

SQL> select id,dbms_lob.getlength(a) length from test1;

        ID     LENGTH
---------- ----------
         1                     
         2          0
```

Comment: My question is. when i read an empty clob column using get_length(clob_data) method. it returns no value, where it should return 0 ?

Comment: @HarryManoharan Most functions will return null if the input is null. For most Oracle strings, a string with no characters is equivalent to NULL. There are zero-length empty CLOBs, as Sam's answer demonstrates, but they are not always used. I think the problem is more likely with your data than with the LOB functionality. Maybe the upgrade changed some data, or maybe it shifted the data around to return unexpected values? But a length functions returning null is perfectly normal in most cases.

Comment: Makes sense thanks alot to both of you i'll check my data again. maybe the values inserted doesn;t represent an empty_clob()